# No Part matches the given query

Tags: python, django

I'm begginer in django. I have a problem with error:

> No Part matches the given query.

**views.py:**

```
from description.models import Part
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def PartyNumView(request, pk=None, page_number = 1):
    all_parties = Part.objects.all()
    current_page = Paginator(all_parties, 10)
    try:
        context = current_page.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        context = current_page.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        context = current_page.page(current_page.num_pages)
    onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk = pk)
    return render_to_response('part_list.html', {'PartyNum': context, 'onePart': onePart})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^parties/(\d+)/$', PartyNumView),
    url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
    url(r'parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
    url(r'^main/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),       #static html
    url(r'^measures/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='IcDesc.html')),       #static html

]
```

And a little bit of **part_list.html:**

```
 {% for object in PartyNum %}

<tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'onePart' pk = object.pk %}"> {{ object.Party_number }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ object.Film }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.Thick }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.Critical_temperature }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.R_s }}</td>

 {% endfor %}
```

In Models.py I have a class Part(models.Model)

Help me please find a mistake.

Comment: Most likely, the Part object at `onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk = pk)` does not exist, and you're getting a 404 from that. Consider removing that line if the pk is None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raising because you are trying to `get` a `Part` instance which is not available in your DB.That is, you are providing a `pk` value via url, and it's not matching with DB.
You can avoid this error by simply querying an existing `Part` object. or, you can modify the response as below,

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse 
def PartyNumView(request, pk=None, page_number = 1):
    all_parties = Part.objects.all()
    current_page = Paginator(all_parties, 10)
    try:
        context = current_page.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        context = current_page.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        context = current_page.page(current_page.num_pages)
    try:
        onePart = Part.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Part.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Part instance not found with pk-{}".format(pk))
    return render_to_response('part_list.html', {'PartyNum': context, 'onePart': onePart})
```

**UPDATE-1**
Update your `urls.py` as below

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<page_number>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
    url(r'^main/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),       #static html
    url(r'^measures/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='IcDesc.html')),       #static html

]
```

Comment: I have a error: Reverse for 'onePart' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 9}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['parti/(?P<pk>\\[\\d]+)/$']

Comment: did you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691843/8283848)?

Comment: Yes, I've try it. But when I delete this urls, I have error 404. I think this error occurs because I must transfer to paginator page_number, but when I delete urls I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 urls pointing to the same view.

```
url(r'^parties/(\d+)/$', PartyNumView),
url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
url(r'^parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
```

The first url you have listed takes precedence, but you're not accepting a PK in that url and your function param lists `pk=None`. So this expression won't work:

```
onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk = pk)
```

Try deleting the first two URLs and leaving the last one as that accepts a PK. Also, in your function params, change `pk=None` to `pk`.

Also, take a look at the final two URLs you have listed. Both point to the same view, so you should decide which one you should keep.